# bash script to search through rows of data looking for match

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have an input file like so.

```
dog
cat
bird
fish
```

I have a main file like so. Each row has different number of fields, but in increments of three (so 3,6,9,12,... fields)

```
dog bird 123       asdf 456 cloud    sam 4444 barbara
bird sdf asdf
asdf 123 fdsa      cat asdff 1223sdf
aaaa fish ffff       ffff fish aaaa
```

I want the program to search the input file and print out the entire line when there is a match from the input list. The trick is that I don't want to check all the columns from the main file, just the first column for each triplet - as follows.

Check column 1 or 4 or 7 for a match from the input list.

- so the word dog matches column 1 from the first row -
- so the word cat matches column 4 from the third row -
- so the word bird matches column 1 from the second row -
- the word fish does NOT match column 1, 4, or 7 - so doesn't count

Make sense?  I have found a way to do this in awk, but it involves sending an array in as a parameter and it is fairly tricky to parse the array out.

Help?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) if ($i in a) {print;next}}'  input main
```

Example:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) if ($i in a) {print;next}}'  input main
dog bird 123       asdf 456 cloud    sam 4444 barbara
bird sdf asdf
asdf 123 fdsa      cat asdff 1223sdf
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1];next}`

  If we are reading the first file, the one with the words, we a the word as a key in associative array `a`.  Then, we skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) if ($i in a) {print;next}`

  For every third field, we check to see if it appears as a key in associative array `a`.  If it does, then we print the line and jump to start over on the `next` line.

Comment: I hope you're not paid by the word.  This is so short it borders on ridiculous, but it does work. Thanks and sorry for delay in getting back to you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the newfangled [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) data type to store the search keys, and then run a loop to check the target words of each line of the main file against the associative array to test if the line matches.

```
INPUT_FILE='input.txt';
MAIN_FILE='main.txt';

## first read in all words from the input file into an associative array
## assume one word per line
declare -A keys=(); while read -r; do keys["$REPLY"]=1; done <"$INPUT_FILE";

## now read in one line at a time from the main file
while read -r; do
    words=($REPLY); ## word splitting
    ## check for a match in multiple-of-3 words
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#words[@]}; i += 3)); do
        if [[ ${keys["${words[i]}"]} ]]; then
            echo "$REPLY"; ## echo the whole matching line
            break; ## don't need to check anymore
        fi;
    done;
done <"$MAIN_FILE";
```

Output:

```
dog bird 123       asdf 456 cloud    sam 4444 barbara
bird sdf asdf
asdf 123 fdsa      cat asdff 1223sdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > trois.awk 
BEGIN {                       # in the beginning
    RS="( +|\n)"              # set input record separator to spaces or newline
} 
NR==FNR {                     # for the first or input file only
    a[$1]                     # store the keywords
    next                      # avoid the rest of the code for the first file
} 
(($1 in a) && FNR%3==1) || i%3 {   # if a keyword matches in place 1, 4, 7, ...
    i++                            # or i counter allows printing (2,3, 5,6 ...)
    printf "%s%s", $1, i%3?OFS:ORS # print it pretty
}
$ awk -f trois.awk file1 file2
dog bird 123
bird sdf asdf
cat asdff 1223sdf
```

In short, `RS` makes `file2` a list of words and if a keyword matches on row number mod 3 == 1 (1, 4, 7, ...), start counter `i` and print the two next words.